# Run SQL Process at specific time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to build a background process that will check and execute a stored procedure (SQL Server 2008R2) that users will schedule on a UI application. I don't want to create a job, I want to handle it myself. So I was planning to run a check every 2 secs for example and check if there is process that rich the specific time and run it.

Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: `WAITFOR TIME` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187331.aspx

Comment: " I don't want to create a job" - why not? That's what the agent is there for....

Comment: yes but in case user cancel the process, I need to be in sync with the job and cancel it too

Comment: *"So I was planning to run a check every 2 secs "*  - and how are you going to do that without a job?

Comment: I can use WAITFOR but is a kind of blocking until it's done, I want to be able to run them in a thread

Comment: ok I'll see what I can do, thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set up a task within SQL Server, you could write an app that makes the DB call, then schedule that app through Windows Task Scheduler.